# Using JavaScript to fade divs in and out in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

Ok.  I am still struggling with getting my tool tips to fade in and out in timed transitions.  A little help we be awesome!

So I want my "fader" divs to start onClick of a button fading in, lasting for 5 seconds, then fading out in order.  Like a quick timed tutorial for my new UI.

Here is my code:

JS

```
function fadeLoop() {

    var counter = 0,
        divs = $('.fader').hide(), // Selecting fader divs instead of each by name.
        dur = 500;

    function showDiv() {
        divs.fadeOut(dur) // hide all divs
            .filter(function(index) {
                return index == counter % divs.length;
            }) // figure out correct div to show
            .delay(dur) // delay until fadeout is finished
            .fadeIn(dur); // and show it
        counter++;
    }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div
    showDiv(); // show first div    
    return setInterval(function() {  // return interval so we can stop the loop
        showDiv(); // show next div
    }, 5 * 1000); // do this every 5 seconds    
};

$(function() {
    var interval;

    $("#start").click(function() {
        if (interval == undefined){
            interval = fadeLoop();
            $(this).val("Stop");
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(interval);
            $(this).val("Start");
            interval = undefined;
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="fader">
    <div id="tutorial1" class="tutorial createquestion1">
        <div class="arrow-w" style="font-size:1em;" >
        </div>
        &nbsp;Start by creating a title and selecting a folder for your question to be stored in.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fader">
    <div id="tutorial2" class="tutorial createquestion2">
        <div class="arrow-w" style="font-size:1em;" >
        </div>
        &nbsp;Categories are key to your reporting effectiveness, be sure to include categories that relate to this question.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fader">
    <div id="tutorial3" class="tutorial createquestion3">
        <div class="arrow-w" style="font-size:1em;" >
        </div>
        &nbsp;Select your options and/or upload an attachment (file, video or audio).
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fader">
    <div id="tutorial4" class="tutorial createquestion4">
        <div class="arrow-n" style="font-size:1em;" >
        </div><br />
        To create questions easier update your question preferences in your account area options.&nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fader">
    <div id="tutorial5" class="tutorial createquestion5">
        <div class="arrow-w" style="font-size:1em;" >
        </div>
        &nbsp;Your rationale can be used to provide feedback to students on this question and you also can use internal comment to track notes on changes, updates, textbook information and more.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fader">
    <div id="tutorial6" class="tutorial createquestion6">Write your questions, answers and you are ready to go.&nbsp;
        <div class="arrow-e" style="font-size:1em;" >
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Start" name="Start" />
```

CSS

```
.tutorial {
    display: table;
    border: 4px solid #8C3087;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px 2px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 2px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 2px #ccc;
    position:absolute;
    padding: 11px;
    font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
    background-color:#ECA100;
    width:200;
    z-index:2000;
    font-size:12pt; 
    color:#000;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.arrow-n,
.arrow-e,
.arrow-s,
.arrow-w {
  /*
   * In Internet Explorer, The"border-style: dashed" will never be
   * rendered unless "(width * 5) >= border-width" is true.
   * Since "width" is set to "0", the "dashed-border" remains
   * invisible to the user, which renders the border just like how
   * "border-color: transparent" renders.
   */
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0.53em;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    display: inline-block;
  /* Use font-size to control the size of the arrow. */
    font-size: 100px;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    text-align:left;
}

.arrow-n {
    border-bottom-width: 1em;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #8C3087;
    bottom: 0.25em;
}

.arrow-e {
    border-left-width: 1em;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #8C3087;
    left: 0.25em;
}

.arrow-s {
    border-top-width: 1em;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #8C3087;
    top: 0.25em;
}

.arrow-w {
    border-right-width: 1em;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #8C3087;
    right: 0.25em;
}

/* Create Multiple Choice Question */
.createquestion1 {
    top:140px;
    left:320px;
    text-align:left;
}
.createquestion2 {
    top:240px;
    left:320px;
    text-align:left;
}
.createquestion3 {
    top:340px;
    left:320px;
    text-align:left;
}
.createquestion4 {
    top:60px;
    right:10px;
    text-align:right !important; 
}
.createquestion5 {
    top:520px;
    left:320px;
    text-align:left;
}
.createquestion6 {
    top:140px;
    left:100px;
    text-align:right !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start by adding an ID to your button so the jQuery click handler registers

```
<input type="button" value="Start" name="Start" id="start" />
```

Comment: It still refuses to start right though, although it is working in jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

Your html needs to correspond with the javascript if you want it to work.

Here is a working version: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NpNXr/6/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="fader tutorial" id="createquestion1">
    <div class="arrow-w" style="font-size:1em;"></div>
    &nbsp;Start by creating a title and selecting a folder for your question to be stored in.
</div>

<div class="fader tutorial" id="createquestion2">
    <div class="arrow-w" style="font-size:1em;"></div>
    &nbsp;Categories are key to your reporting effectiveness, be sure to include categories that relate to this question.
</div>

<div class="fader tutorial" id="createquestion3">
    <div class="arrow-w" style="font-size:1em;"></div>
    &nbsp;Select your options and/or upload an attachment (file, video or audio).
</div>

<div class="fader tutorial" id="createquestion4">
    <div class="arrow-w" style="font-size:1em;"></div>
   To create questions easier update your question preferences in your account area options.&nbsp
</div>

<div class="fader tutorial" id="createquestion5">
    <div class="arrow-w" style="font-size:1em;"></div>
    &nbsp;Your rationale can be used to provide feedback to students on this question and you also can use internal comment to track notes on changes, updates, textbook information and more.
</div>

<div class="fader tutorial" id="createquestion6">
    <div class="arrow-w" style="font-size:1em;"></div>
   Write your questions, answers and you are ready to go.&nbsp;
</div>

<input type="button" value="Start" id="start"/>
```

​**CSS**

```
#start{
    right:1em;
    top:1em;
    padding:1em;
}

.tutorial {
    display: table;
    border: 4px solid #8C3087;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px 2px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 2px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 2px #ccc;
    position:absolute;
    padding: 11px;
    font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
    background-color:#ECA100;
    width:200;
    z-index:2000;
    font-size:12pt; 
    color:#000;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.arrow-n,
.arrow-e,
.arrow-s,
.arrow-w {
  /*
   * In Internet Explorer, The"border-style: dashed" will never be
   * rendered unless "(width * 5) >= border-width" is true.
   * Since "width" is set to "0", the "dashed-border" remains
   * invisible to the user, which renders the border just like how
   * "border-color: transparent" renders.
   */
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0.53em;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    display: inline-block;
  /* Use font-size to control the size of the arrow. */
    font-size: 100px;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    text-align:left;
}

.arrow-n {
    border-bottom-width: 1em;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #8C3087;
    bottom: 0.25em;
}

.arrow-e {
    border-left-width: 1em;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #8C3087;
    left: 0.25em;
}

.arrow-s {
    border-top-width: 1em;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #8C3087;
    top: 0.25em;
}

.arrow-w {
    border-right-width: 1em;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #8C3087;
    right: 0.25em;
}

/* Create Multiple Choice Question */
#createquestion1 {
    top:140px;
    left:320px;
    text-align:left;
}
#createquestion2 {
    top:240px;
    left:320px;
    text-align:left;
}
#createquestion3 {
    top:340px;
    left:320px;
    text-align:left;
}
#createquestion4 {
    top:60px;
    right:10px;
    text-align:right !important; 
}
#createquestion5 {
    top:520px;
    left:320px;
    text-align:left;
}
#createquestion6 {
    top:140px;
    left:100px;
    text-align:right !important;
}
```

​

Comment: This works great in jsfiddle!  I still can't get it to run on my page though...  I have .asp page with an if else statement that pulls up the tool tips.  When it is selected, all the divs pop up at the same time, and the button does nothing... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ChristopherWadeEarnhart I would have to see the if else statement.

Comment: <!--#include file="header.asp"-->
<% if Request("interactive") = "on" then %>

<!--html content-->

<% end if %>

Comment: Im sorry I cant further help you with that problem

Comment: Thank you Eric, you were a big help!